# Perform CRUD operations on product class?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm a newbie to Django-oscar and I'm trying to develop a simple CRUD operation on `Product`. I've forked the catalogue app and created a `views.py` file

I fired the query `Product.objects.create(title='Hello')` and a product does get created with the following error:

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attributes'*

```
product_title = 'MyPhone'
upc=987654321
product_class = ProductClass.objects.get_or_create(name='Phone')
def createProduct(request):
        line1
    product.name = product_title
    product.product_class = product_class
    product.upc=upc
    product.save()
```

When I put `product=Product()` in line1 I get the following error:

*Cannot assign "(, False)": "Product.product_class" must be a "ProductClass" instance.*

When I put `product = Product.objects.create(upc=upc)` I get the following error :

*NoneType' object has no attribute 'attributes'*

Anyone guide me on how to write a simple create operation?

Comment: There's something strange in the model definition. Post that, plus the *full* traceback.

Comment: please provide more explanations or carefully look into my answer.

Comment: You should give some feedback about what you get after applying the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProductClass, Product, Category, ProductCategory = get_classes(
    'catalogue.models', ('ProductClass', 'Product', 'Category',
                         'ProductCategory'))
create_from_breadcrumbs = get_class('catalogue.categories', 'create_from_breadcrumbs')


 def _create_item(product_class, category_str, upc, title,
                     description, stats):
        # Ignore any entries that are NULL
        if description == 'NULL':
            description = ''

        # Create item class and item
        product_class, __ = ProductClass.objects.get_or_create(name=product_class)
        try:
            item = Product.objects.get(upc=upc)
            stats['updated_items'] += 1
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            item = Product()
            stats['new_items'] += 1
        item.upc = upc
        item.title = title
        item.description = description
        item.product_class = product_class
        item.save()

        # Category
        cat = create_from_breadcrumbs(category_str)
        ProductCategory.objects.update_or_create(product=item, category=cat)

        return item
```

This is the actual way to manipulate products with provided information to the function in django oscar. For better design decisions you need to follow this convention. Modify it as you want. Let me know if you want more help. Thank you.

Comment: I will try this, give me sometime

Comment: Sure let me know what you get and let me know if you need help

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I was able to successfully make it work. I was using if-else and I switched to try-except as per your code and it worked! I have another question, can we use the same code to change the category using ```create_from_breadcrumbs```?

Comment: Sure, you can. If it helped you please make it accepted and give an upvote.